# Expanding $(1+x^3)^{-1/3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have tried to create a sum formula $$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -1/3 \\
    n    \\
    \end{pmatrix}x^{3n}
$$

However, the first term I found $\frac{-x^3}3$ was not true. I think I have to substitute $x^3$ with something but I don't know how.

Comment: Your expansion looks correct. Why do you think that it is “not true”?

Comment: @MartinR yeah my $\sum$ was true... Although, first term was $1$ (I've missed that)

Comment: Your expansion looks good. It gives $$\left(1+x^3\right)^{-1/3}=1-\frac13x^3+\frac29x^6-\frac{14}{81}x^9+\dots$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular expansion try using the well know form:

$$\left(1+x\right)^n =1+ \frac{n}{1!}x^1+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}x^2+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}x^3+\cdots $$

Comment: Isn't that what he did? Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @MartinR Yes Martin, but I thought his/her issue was in the binomial coefficients, the expansion above in my answer explicitly lays out the series. Maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for expanding the series, I've missed the $a_0$ term was 1